# embedded fonts aren't loading on live server, but do load on local machine

Tags: html, css

site in progress: http://zrrdigitalmedia.com/

I've been building this site on my desktop machine and it's been looking as I've expected it to so far. I recently deemed the site done and uploaded it to my web hosting space. However all of the @font-face embedded fonts aren't loading. They load as expected when viewing the site on my local machine via FF24 & Chrome30. I'm completely puzzled why this is happening.

I link the font stylesheet in the head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/stylesheet.css">
```

And refer to it in my main CSS file like:

```
.headerText{
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    font-size: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666666;
}
```

While the fonts/stylesheet.css has all the embedded fonts in this format (they were generated using [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    src: url('bebasneue-webfont.eot');
    src: url('bebasneue-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('bebasneue-webfont.svg#bebas_neueregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

All of my fonts are in the /fonts folder. I literally copied my file structure from my HD to the web space. I've used this method before and it worked without any problems. And yet this problem has risen!

Any suggestions/advice/help welcome! I'm totally at a loss for ideas here. Thanks!

Comment: Use the Force¹, Luke² …! _¹ Force here being your browser’s error console, that clearly tells you what’s up_ / _² And next time please do so before asking._

Comment: thanks CBoe - i've never used the errors panel before in firebug. no idea why the fonts folder was throwing a 403 - but i deleted the folder on the server, made a new one, then uploaded the folder contents from my HD to that new folder and now everything's good. Thanks!